# How do I compare nested lists generated from a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I have originally started with a csv file of 52 rows of the form [name, attribute 1, attribute 2]. I have imported the csv file and created all possible combinations of size with 2 for each row, so I have a list of something like this:

```
([Bill, Long, Blonde], [Sally, Short, Blonde]),
([Bobby, Long, Brown], [James, Short, Orange])
```

etc...

I want to be able to compare both attribute 1 and attribute 2 and then ultimately weight it so I can find groups of 2 that have the most in common. I am struggling to find a way to easily compare attributes 1 and 2 without dismantling the groups in the first place.

The code I have written so far is below:

```
import csv
from itertools import combinations


with open('dc.csv', 'r') as f:

  csvreader = csv.reader(f)

  comb = combinations(csv.reader(f), 2)

  for i in list(comb):
    print (i)
```

EDIT:
My desired output is to have a list in order of the best matching to least matching sets.  So something like:

```
([James, Short, Orange], [Bridgett, Short, Orange], 2)
([Bill, Long, Blonde], [Sally, Short, Blonde], 1),
([Bobby, Long, Brown], [James, Short, Orange], 0),
```

That is that since James and Bridgett match on both hair color (1) and hair length (1) they get a score of 2, and so on and so forth.  So i can then order them by who matches the most and who matches the least.

Comment: unclear question. what's the desired output?

Comment: What is expected output of the example you gave? What do you mean by attribute? Is it the names like Bill,Long etc. If that is the case what are the weights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've understood, what you want is to calculate the "likeness" of each element.

So here's what I did:

```
a = [['Bill', 'Long','Blonde'], ['Sally', 'Short', 'Blonde'], ['Bobby', 'Long', 'Brown'], ['James', 'Short', 'Orange']]

def likenessCalculator(groupA, indexA, groupB, indexB):
  # Function that calculates how close the attributes are
  likeness = 0
  if groupA[1] == groupB[1]:
    likeness += 1
  if groupA[2] == groupB[2]:
    likeness += 1
  return (groupA, groupB, likeness)

results = []

for idx, element in enumerate(a):
  for idx2, element2 in enumerate(a):
    # Here I iterate through the array, and for every element, I compare it with each other element
    # This code doesn't remove duplicates yet, but it shouldn't be hard to implement.
    results.append(likenessCalculator(element, idx, element2, idx2))

print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, once you get the list from the csv file, you can try something like this:

```
the_list = [([Bill, Long, Blonde], [Sally, Short, Blonde]), ([Bobby, Long, Brown], [James, Short, Orange])]
result= []
for names in the_list:
    n = len(set(names[0]).intersection(set(names[1])))
    new = list(names)
    new.append(n)
    result.append(new)
print(result)
```

And you will have your final list in the `result` variable